# Что означает знак «Скрытый талант»?

Tags: обсуждение, знаки

Получил знак «**Скрытый талант**». В описании знака указано следующее:

> *Нулевой рейтинг принятых ответов: более 5 и 20% от общего количества.*

Вот только я не могу понять этого описания. За что знак-то? :) Не могли бы подробнее описать, за что присуждается данный знак? Я понимаю, что за ответы, но что-то не понятно как он вдруг появился :)

Comment: ты написал много ответов, некоторые из них приняты, из принятых, из этих принятых у некоторых рейтинг 0. Вот таких ответов, принятых и с рейтингом 0 у тебя больше 5 штук, и больше 20% от общего количества

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за пояснение, но можно вопрос, а почему система только сейчас дала знак? Крайний принятый ответ с нулевым рейтингом я давал 11 сентября...

Comment: Это значит, что сейчас плюс/минус сколько-то часов выполнились условия того, что _принятых и с рейтингом 0_ стало 5 и больше и _больше 20% от общего количества_

Comment: Ах вот оно что...точно, что-то я не сразу сообразил. Подумал, что баг, а это фича :)

Comment: Предлагаю [улучшить описание знака](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3774/).

Comment: @Grundy, от общего количества рейтинга, репутации или ответов?

Comment: @Bharata от общего количества ответов, которые были приняты (отмечены в качестве верного)

Comment: @DenisBubnov, теперь понятно! Благо дарю за ответ! Было бы неплохо добавить это в описание, а то совсем там непонятно так как сейчас написано.

Comment: Я так понял, что этот знак можно получить только пока мало ответов. Чтобы при 10к репутации триггернуло -- я бы тоже на баг списал. Вы реально представляете, сколько это нулевых принятых вопросов? На секундочку: у Дениса 350 ответов, из них 192 принятых, ну допустим для ровного счета, что их 200: это надо чтобы > 40 вопросов было принято, но с нулём. Знаете, это надо так постараться....

Comment: @AK ну, 26 сентября 2016 года у меня не было 10К репутации, но тогда мне показалось это странным (не помню сколько было репутации, но ответов было достаточно много). Это я так, немного отредактировал текст вопроса  :)

Comment: Ответы на вопросы новичков часто принимаются и остаются с нулевым рейтингом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно чтобы среди твоих принятых ответов нулевой рейтинг имело хотя бы 6 (или 5?), причём это количество должно составлять не менее 20% от всех твоих принятых ответов.

В данный момент у тебя:

- [Принятых ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A189339+isaccepted%3A1): 194
- [Принятых ответов с нулевым рейтингом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A189339+isaccepted%3A1+votes%3A0..0): 30

Считаем: `30 > 5 && 30 / 194 > 0.2` - не выполняется - сейчас бы знак не дали))
А у меня: `125 > 5 && 125 / 887 > 0.2` - уже тоже не выполняется :)

---

А вот те же запросы для текущего участника:

- [Принятых ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+isaccepted%3A1)
- [Принятых ответов с нулевым рейтингом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+isaccepted%3A1+votes%3A0..0)

Comment: Смотрел-смотрел на свои числа (на текущий момент из 235 принятых ответов только 21 с нулём в рейтинге, а надо 47), понял что получить подобный знак ну ооочень сложно. Но всё-таки способ есть: нужно переводить много вопросов с enso (оформляя их самоответами), подобные ответы редко плюсуют -- и в заплюсованых ответах не ставить галку, чтобы не ухудшать коэффициент. А потом когда накопится достаточно ответов без апвоутов разом кааак поставить сразу штук тридцать галок ;)

Comment: @AK, а я оба знака успел получить :)