# Описания знаков «Скрытый талант» и «Непризнанный гений»

Tags: предложение, локализация, знаки

Нынешние описания [трудно понять](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3736/). Давайте их улучшим?

> `Скрытый талант`
>   Нулевой рейтинг принятых ответов: более 5 и 20% от общего количества
>
> `Непризнанный гений`
>   Нулевой рейтинг принятых ответов, более 10 и 25% от общего количества

[На английском](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

> `Tenacious`
>   Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total
>
> `Unsung Hero`
>   Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

Answer (score 4):

Описания состоят из двух частей. Сначала объясняем знак, потом перечисляем требования. На английском эти части отделены двоеточием, а на русском их можно сделать самостоятельными предложениями. Так легче воспринимать.

Знаки утешают, когда пользу приносишь, а коллеги не хвалят. Поэтому добавим в объяснение драматизма. Разобьём первое предложение союзом `но`, чтобы противопоставить друг другу начало и конец объяснения.

> `Скрытый талант`
> Ответы приняты, но у них нулевой рейтинг. Таких ответов более 5 и более 20%.
>
> `Непризнанный гений`
> Ответы приняты, но у них нулевой рейтинг. Таких ответов более 10 и более 25%.

Comment: "Более 5 штук и 20%" - чтобы не было повтора слова "более".

Comment: @Qwertiy так получается, что **ровно** 20%, а это неверно. Считаю, что в концовку нужно еще добавить `от общего кол-ва ваших ответов`

Comment: @Qwertiy `штук` еще плохо тем, что нужны множественные формы. Скорее всего их нет, но надо проверить в transifex.

Comment: @Qwertiy "Более 5" и "более 20%" - два равноправных условия. Поэтому хочу подчеркнуть, что есть два условия и что их надо выполнить одновременно. А запись "более 5 штук и 20%" склеивает два  простых условия в одно замысловатое. Приходится дешифровывать текст, чтобы его понять. Имхо.

Comment: @alexolut Думал об этом, но получается хвост размером во всю предшествующую фразу :( Пробовал варианты: `20% от общего количества`, `20% от общего числа`, `20% от всех ваших ответов`, `20% от всех`... Но не смог себе объяснить, чем они лучше, чем просто `20%`.

Comment: Как–то сложно получается, если честно. Возможно можно как–то совсем переписать? Предложенные варианты, на первый взгляд, не кажутся проще.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Спасибо за критику. Добавлю другой ответ, если придумаю альтернативу.